# Pass enums by value or reference?

Tags: c++, enums

My general rule is to pass by value for primitive types and pass by reference for objects (obviously const'd if need be). However, I'm not sure what route to take with enumerated types. I'd assume that pass by value is preferred since they are seemingly small, but I'd like to hear others thoughts.

Comment: enums are often used as a way of defining constants, RED, BLUE, ON, OFF etc. If you think about how you would pass a constant to your function then you could probably come to the solution to your question yourself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No other thoughts. An enum is just an integral value in a fancy dress (or suit, if you prefer). It has no internal structure and will travel in a register given a chance. If you'd pass an int by value, pass an enum that way, too.

Comment: `3.9.1/7`: "A synonym for integral type is integer type."

Answer (score 1):

Enum have a underlying representation type which is an integer types.  There are no more reasons (and no less) to pass them by reference that there are reasons to pass integer types by reference.